# Split Multi-Line Cell into Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code for splitting a multi-line cell in Excel into several rows and it works well with a single cell. However, if I expand the range, seen below, I receive the `Type Mismatch` error message.

```
Dim SplitText

SplitText = Split(Range("A1:B1").Value, vbLf)
Range("A1:B1").Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
```

So far, I have had no luck figuring out what I am missing.

Comment: ***Welcome to stack Overflow!***  I suspect you're trying to refer to a ***merged cell*** with `A1:B1`, is that correct?  If so, try just `A1`.  If that doesn't work, we're going to need some more information showing *what you have* and and example of *what you are trying to do*, and more about what you've tried so far.  See "[mcve]", and there's more good info at "[help]" and also "[ask]" as well as "[help/on-topic]"... Another method might be Text-To-Columns, depending on what your data looks like, and where it is.

Comment: @ashleedawg It works with just A1. The user L42 has luckily provided a solution. However, I am just encountering one more error with his approach. Thanks!

Comment: I'm unclear on whether your issue is solved since you replied to my comment, but if your original issue is fixed and there's a new one, it's best to start a new question specific to the new issue.  (Stack Overflow is intended as more if a "wiki of specific problems" rather than one-on-one support.)

Comment: @ashleedawg The issue is solved, which is why I had marked it as such. As reflected in my comment below, the `Type Mismatch` error is due to a transpose length limit and I have a workaround for it. Thank you again for the support!

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function) expects a string argument. You will have to do it one by one.
 Try something like:

```
Dim SplitText
Dim myRange As Range, r As Range

Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:B1") '/* change Sheet1 to actual sheet */

For Each r In myRange
    SplitText = Split(r, vbLf)
    r.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1) = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I ran your suggestion and it works but oddly enough, I get a `Type Mismatch` error on this line `k.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1) = Application.Transpose(SplitText)`. I had to change r to k to avoid a duplicate declaration.

Comment: I figured out that the `Type Mismatch` error on my end is due to the transpose length limit. It will show up for the range A1:MT1 but not for example A1:K1. I'll need to figure out a workaround for this. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Francis You can take a look at two possible work around. One is using a 2D array and assigning it directly to range without the transpose. You will have to loop of course. Another is using a [`ListBox`](http://excelmatters.com/2013/05/21/transposing-an-array-using-an-in-memory-listbox/).

Comment: Thanks! :) I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you, do keep in mind it does also insert new rows for which to fill as opposed to filling existing rows with the content. If you do not need that, simply remove the first `For Each` loop and the row insert statement.

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim MaxSize As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:B1")
    MaxSize = 0

    For Each cell In rng
        Dim CurrentSize As Integer
        CurrentSize = UBound(Split(cell.Value, vbLf))

        If CurrentSize > MaxSize Then
            MaxSize = CurrentSize
        End If
    Next

    Rows((rng.Row + 1) & ":" & (rng.Row + MaxSize)).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    For Each cell In rng
        Dim SplitText
        SplitText = Split(cell.Value, vbLf)
        cell.Resize(UBound(SplitText) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(SplitText)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your response! I tried your suggestion and get the message that the variable "cell" isn't defined. I entered `Dim cell As Range` but unfortunately it won't work.